# Let be $B$ a basis for $span(M)$ then $B\subset M$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $X$ a vectorial space with $M\subset X$ and $B$ a basis for $span(M)$ then $B\subset M$?

*I can't to use that $span(M)$ is the set of all lineal combinations of $M$*

My definition of $span(M)$ is $\bigcap_{Y\in A}Y$ with $A=${$Y: Y$ is subespace of $X$ and $M\subseteq Y$}

---

Comment: No. Eg: $M=(e_1+e_2,e_1-e_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $B=(e_1,e_2)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ is not a subspace, there is no reason for this to be true. For example, let $M$ be a set containing a single nonzero vector $v$. Then $\{\frac12 v\} $ is a basis for the span of $M$ but is not a subset of $M$, where $X$ is a vector space over a field of characteristic other than $2$.

Comment: span(M) is a sub space even if M is not.

Comment: @NicNic True. But the question is whether the basis is a subset of $M$. It is always a subset of the span.

Answer (score 1):

No, in $X=\Bbb R^2$ with $M = \{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix},  \begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$, then $\operatorname{span}(M)=X$ but we can take $\{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$ as a base, which is not a subset of $M$.

A base for $\operatorname{span}(M)$ will of course be a subset of $\operatorname{span}(M)$ but that's trivial.

Also true: a spanning subset $M$ will contain **some** base for its span, but not necessarily some pregiven base..